# Create Columns from a XML Data Type column with an undefined number of elements in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a column of XML data type with the following contents:

```
<Station>
  <row>
    <lid>1055</lid>
    <sname>some name</sname>
    <sipadress>111.222.011.112</sipadress>
    <sdescription>Some description</sdescription>

    ... many more elements ...

  </row>
</Station>
```

I'd like to have a view or a result which looks something like that:

```
lid |sname    |sipadress      |sdescription    | ...
-----------------------------------------------------
1055|some name|111.222.011.112|Some description| ...
```

I've searched for hours and tried `sp_xml_preparedocument`, `CROSS APPLY`... but for every solution, you have to specify the elements, respectively the column-names (`lid, sname, sipadress...`)

I'm searching for a way to get all the descendants of `<row>`, wherever the number, and without specifying the name of them and then to create columns for them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a combination of the query provided by @marc_s and the dynamic pivot in the dupe. If the columns you want is unknown before execution you have to build the query dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @input TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlContent XML)

INSERT INTO @input VALUES(1, '<Station>
  <row>
    <lid>1055</lid>
    <sname>some name</sname>
    <sipadress>111.222.011.112</sipadress>
    <sdescription>Some description</sdescription>
    <anything>test</anything>
    <anything2>test</anything2>
    <anything3>test</anything3>
  </row>
</Station>'), (2, '<Station>
  <row>
    <lid>1055</lid>
    <sname>some name</sname>
    <sipadress>111.222.011.112</sipadress>
    <sdescription>Some description</sdescription>
    <something>test</something>
    <something2>test</something2>
    <something3>test</something3>
  </row>
</Station>')

SELECT
    ID,
    ElementName = XC.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    ElementValue = XC.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(250)')
FROM
    @input
CROSS APPLY
    XmlContent.nodes('/Station/row/*') AS XT(XC)
```

I get this output from it:

[image]

The XQuery expression `/Station/row/*` just selects **all** elements directly under each `<row>` node - no matter how many there are and what they're called.

Then I use the XQuery function `local-name(.)` to get the *name* of the XML element, and the `(.)` notation to get the *value* of the XML elment.

Mind you: this works for all strings - any other things (like `<lid>` which appears to be an `int`) will also be returned as a `varchar(250)` in this approach - but you do get **all direct child nodes** and their values.

Comment: Thanks. I had this before, yes. But isn't there a way to create columns out of the element names and fill them with the corresponding element values? Another way I thought of would be your answer and then somehow use the rows to create columns.